# What makes you think so? Why without does?

Tags: questions, do-support

I don't understand why in the sentence " what makes you think so" we don't use "do" like "what does  make you think so?" It's present simple. It is a question.
What do I miss here?
I would be grateful for another examples!

Comment: _What_ is the subject of _makes_. The rule of _do_-support only applies when an auxiliary verb is required (like it is for negation or subject-auxiliary inversion), but subject-auxiliary inversion does not apply to subjects that are _wh_-words in questions -- it's _Who hit you?_, not *_Who did hit you?_ or *_Did who hit you?_ There are different rules and they interact together; _do_-support is part of the mix.

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler ! It makes sense. It's like "Who called you last night? ". Who is the subject, so I don't use "do".

Comment: Funny thing, I find these explanations using formal grammar terms overly complex for English learners. I taught English seven years and never provided technical linguistic explanations....just saying....by the way: /Who did hit you/ is grammatical whereas Did who hit you? is not...

Answer (score 1):

The use of [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) within a [wh-word question](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/wh-question-words.htm) only normally occurs in contexts where a possible answer has already been (explicitly or implicitly) provided and rejected...

> *We all know Kojak hates you, so answer me this: [Who **does** love ya, baby?](http://www.shmoop.com/quotes/who-loves-ya-baby.html)*

You can get more or less the same implication *without* do-support by placing heavy stress on ***Who*** in the above example, but note that [***do-support*** applies to every main verb in English, except auxiliary verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/2637) (and *the verb **be** is always treated as an auxiliary verb, even if it's the only verb in its clause*). Thus in the case of...

> *We all know Kojak hates you, so answer me this: Who is your secret lover, baby?*

...where the implied "rejection" (of a default or previously-suggested response) can be conveyed equally well by placing heavy stress on either ***Who*** or ***is***. Offhand I can't think of any obvious difference in nuance depending which of those two words you stress, but you definitely can't include ***does*** there.

---

In Shakespeare's time, OP's example *What does make you think so?* could feasibly occur in contexts where no such rejection is implied, in which case the word ***does*** wouldn't be stressed. But today it would only be likely *with* that stress, in contexts where some possible justification for the addressee's belief has already been proposed and rejected...

> *If you still think he's innocent despite all the evidence, what **does** make you think so?*

(Which I admit is a little contrived, but again the same effect can be acheived by stressing ***what***.)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as

> What *makes* you think so?
>   *what causes you to think that way*
>
> Why *do* you think so?
>   *what causes you to think that way*
>
> I really don't understand him, what *does make* him think that way?

in the last case (with heavy emphasis on *does*) *does* is used as an intensifier for emphasis

> What *does* make you think so?

is more of a rhetorical question, whereas

> What makes you think so?

is a standard question asking one's thinking behind an answer or belief.